# How do I get js and css to display in Django?

Tags: python, django

I've got a template, a.html, which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="reg.js"></script>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}reg.js"></script>
```

You'll need to make sure you're [serving static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) correctly, and you'll need `"django.core.context_processors.media"` in the [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#template-context-processors) setting.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't set up your web server to alias those to their corresponding static media.

Answer (score 0):

Since your URLs can have arbitrary path depths, you need to get absolute path to your JS. e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/reg.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, make sure you have those files setup at the said locations by adding something like (r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.CORE_MEDIA_ROOT}),

On production, the main webserver (apache or nginx etc.) should serve the content instead of your django application.

Re